# derivative with respect to scalar variable

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

What is the result of the following expression:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (\mathbf{x} - a \mathbf{1})^T \Sigma (\mathbf{x} -  a \mathbf{1})$,

where $a$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{x}$ is a $K \times 1$ column vector, and $\Sigma$ is a $K\times K$ matrix. I can compute the derivative if $a$ is also a vector, which is given as:

$-2\Sigma(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$,

but could not find the solution when $a$ is scalar.

Comment: How do you subtract a scalar from a vector as in $\mathbf x-a$?

Comment: ${\mathbf x}-a$ makes no sense

Comment: I actually use same value for each dimension, sorry for mis-notation. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your notation could still be improved, since your $\mathbf{1} $ symbol is more often used to denote the identity matrix, which cannot be the case. Let me restate the formula in terms of the symbol $\mathbf{y}$, which represents the same array of ones but is less confusing:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (\mathbf{x} - a \mathbf{y})^T \Sigma (\mathbf{x} -  a \mathbf{y})
$$

Which, in terms of components reads (summation implied for repeated indices):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left( (x_i - a y_i) \Sigma_{ij} (x_j - a y_j) \right ) = y_i \Sigma_{ij} (a y_j - x_j) + (a y_i - x_i) \Sigma_{ij} y_j
$$

Or, in the initial notation,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (\mathbf{x} - a \mathbf{y})^T \Sigma (\mathbf{x} -  a \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{y}^T \Sigma (a \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}) +  (a \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})^T \Sigma \mathbf{y}
$$

Comment: Note that if $\Sigma$ is a symmetric matrix, the two terms in your result are equal, which simplifies things a bit.